# Push only specific number of values to form array

Tags: angular, formarray

I would like to know whether it is possible to push a specific number of values into a form array.
So I have a function which gets an array as argument.
I then calculate the remaining places of the form fields.

I want then check whether the length of the text array exceeds the calculated remaining places, if so (eg. remaining places: 5 and text array: 7) only the first text values (in this example the first 5 of 7) should be inserted in the form. If it does not exceed I want to push all values to the form.

```
addTextToForm(textArr: string[]): void {
          

        let remainingPlaces = (this.maxPlaces - (this.form.get(type) as FormArray).length);

        textArr.forEach(text=>{
          
            if(textArr.length>remainingPlaces){
                (this.form.get(type) as FormArray).push(this.formBuilder.control(text));

            }
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let targetArray = []; // Array you want to only ever be 3 elements long

let sourceArray = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]; // The array you want to copy into the targetArray

let remainingPlaces = 3 - targetArray.length // Your calculation to work out remaining spaces

targetArray = [ ...targetArray, ...sourceArray.slice( 0, remainingPlaces ) ]; // Combine existing targetArray with the first three values of sourceArray

console.log( targetArray ); // returns [ 1, 2, 3 ]
```

This is not optimised or doing any checking for things like remainingPlaces being out of bounds, it's just to show you roughly how to achieve this.

Comment: I dont quite understand whether its working with formarray?